# jOOQ asynchronous batch insert

Tags: java, asynchronous, jooq

I want to insert a large number of rows into my database. I've seen that jOOQ has batch support, so I can do the following:

```
dslContext.batchInsert(myListOfRecords).execute()
```

However, this is synonymous. jOOQ has many other asynchronous APIs, is there one for batch inserts?

If not, is it safe to simply wrap the call to `execute` in a `CompletableFuture`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.12, these `executeAsync()` methods are indeed missing on the `org.jooq.Batch` type. See: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9806

However, they don't do anything magic. If you look at the implementation of `AbstractQuery.executeAsync(Executor)`, this is what it's doing (as of jOOQ 3.12):

```
@Override
public final CompletionStage<Integer> executeAsync(Executor executor) {
    return ExecutorProviderCompletionStage.of(
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(blocking(this::execute), executor), () -> executor
    );
}
```

Two things that jOOQ does that you may not need to do yourself:

1. It wraps `CompletableFuture` in a proxy that keeps a reference to your `Executor`, in order to run subsequent tasks *also* on that executor, instead of defaulting back to the common `ForkJoinPool`. IMO a significant mistake in `CompletableFuture`'s design.
2. It wraps the synchronous execution (`this::execute`) in a `blocking()` wrapper, which conveniently wraps the logic in `ForkJoinPool.managedBlock()`. This is recommended when running blocking work in a `ForkJoinPool`